# replace segment of a URL with regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a button that takes a value from a checkbox and inserts it dynamically into a URL parameter. the URL looks like this:

`example.com/search?q=searchterm&site=site1&page=1`

`&site=site1` is what is being updated dynamically by the value of a checkbox. My code for that looked like below at first:

```
$("#apply-filter").click(function() {
    var filterSite;
    var filterSelection;
    var filterUrl;
    filterSite = "http://" + location.host + location.pathname + location.search;
    filterSelection = $('.search-filter-dialog input[type="checkbox"]:checked').val();
    filterUrl = '&site=' + filterSelection + '&page=1';
    console.log(filterUrl + " - " + filterSite);
    window.location.replace(filterUrl);
  });
```

The problem with the first approach is when you click the button multiple times, it just adds the new parameters to the URL, so it ends up looking like:

`example.com/search?q=searchterm&site=site1&page=1&site=site2&page=1&site=site3&page=1`

When I only need to change `&site=site3&page=1` - I tried using a regex to select that part of the URL and replace it with the new one. My attempt at that is below:

```
$("#apply-filter").click(function() {
    var filterSite;
    var filterSelection;
    var filterUrl;
    filterSite = "http://" + location.host + location.pathname + location.search;
    filterSelection = $('.search-filter-dialog input[type="checkbox"]:checked').val();
    filterUrl = filterSite + '&site=' + filterSelection + '&page=1';
    var url = filterUrl.match(/&([^ ]*)/)[1];
    console.log(filterUrl + " - " + filterSite);
    window.location.replace(url, filterUrl);
  });
```

What this block does is remove the search query and just returns

`example.com/site=site1&page=1` which gives a 404.

I need to somehow update a segment of a URL, and not the entire thing. I believe I need to do some sort of regex to target it and change it. What are the next steps? How can I update a certain section of a URL?

EDIT: This is where it stands now:

```
// apply filter, go to page
  $("#apply-filter").click(function() {
      var filterSite;
      var filterSelection;
      var filterUrl;
      filterSite = "http://" + location.host + location.pathname + location.search;
      filterSelection = $('.search-filter-dialog input[type="checkbox"]:checked').val();
      filterUrl = filterSite + '&site=' + filterSelection + '&page=1';
      var url = filterUrl.match(/&([^ ]*)/)[1];
      // console.log(filterUrl + " - " + filterSite);
      if (window.location.href.indexOf("&site=") > -1) {
        filterSite.replace(/&site=\d+/,'&site=' + filterSelection);
        window.location.replace(filterSite);
        console.log(filterSite);
      } else {
        window.location.replace(filterUrl);
      }
  });
```

but the `.replace()` method doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Why don't you store `filterSite` before/outside of your click handler? This way its value never changes again, and you just append the new data whenever someone clicks your filter button.

Comment: Maybe try grouping? `(example.com\/search\?q=searchterm)(\&site=site\d)(\&page=\d)` so you could then pull out or replace whole groups. In this case Group 2 would contain `&site=site1`

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I got it wrong:

You have something like this: *example.com/search?q=searchterm&site=site1&page=1* and you need to update ONLY THIS PART: **&site=site1**.

One way:

```
filterSite.replace(/&site=site\d+/,'&site=site' + filterSelection);
```

This works only if the updatable part of the url is ALWAYS going to be of the form `&site=site<number>`, ie: `filterSelection` is always a number

anyhow, let me know

REGARDING YOUR EDIT:

Assuming what you mean by *The .replace() method won't change the parameter*, is that the URL won't change, you are right: when you do this:

```
filterSite.replace(/&site=\d+/,'&site=' + filterSelection);
```

what you are modifying is the variable `filterSite`, the page won't automatically reload to the new url, which I think is what you intend after seeing this other line:

```
window.location.replace(filterSite);
```

replace it with:

```
window.open(filterSite);
```

to make the page *go* to the new url

More about [window.open and its arguments](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)

One last thing, I noticed you are using `/&site=\d+/,'&site=' + filterSelection` as args for `replace` which will not match `example.com/search?q=searchterm&site=site1&page=1`. So, unless you changed the structure of the url, you might want to look on that too.

let me know

Comment: Yes, that is correct! Playing with this suggestion now.

Comment: I updated my question with new code. The `.replace()` method won't change the parameter.

Comment: do I need to match the entire URL or just the segment?

Comment: what I meant in the last paragraph is that `/&site=\d+/,'&site=' + filterSelection` is NOT what I wrote in my answer as the args of **replace**, it was `/&site=site\d+/,'&site=site' + filterSelection`, is this your doubt?

Comment: The site is different every time. I need to somehow check if `&site=` is in the URL and do something with that.

Comment: do something like what, changing whatever is between `&site=` and `&page`??

Answer (score 0):

### URL Constructor

```
EXAMPLE: 1
;
   var uri = new URL( "http://example.com/search?q=searchterm&site=site1&page=1" );

        uri.searchParams.has("q");
        >> true

        uri.searchParams.set( "site", "site2" );
        uri.searchParams.set( "page", "2" );

        uri.href;
        >> "http://example.com/search?q=searchterm&site=site2&page=2"
;
```

**Browser Suport:** ( ? )[ Chrome 49, Firefox 44, Opera 36, IE12 ]

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to use A POST request method and Jquery has already a method to construct that params to send based in the form

https://api.jquery.com/serialize/